# First record in SQL statement

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to link and additional table to filter by the plant in doing so create multiple records for each entry. I am looking to just get the first entry for one.

```
SELECT 
    OrderHead.CreditOverride, 
    OrderHead.OpenOrder, Customer.CreditHold, 
    OrderHead.OrderNum, Customer.Name, 
    OrderHead.EntryPerson, OrderHead.OrderDate, 
    Customer.TermsCode, OrderHead.ShipToCustNum, OrderRel.Plant
FROM  
    Customer 
INNER JOIN
    OrderHead ON Customer.Company = OrderHead.Company 
             AND Customer.CustNum = OrderHead.BTCustNum 
INNER JOIN
    OrderRel ON OrderHead.OrderNum = OrderRel.OrderNum
WHERE 
    (OrderHead.CreditOverride = 0) 
    AND (OrderHead.OpenOrder = 1)  
    AND (Customer.CreditHold = 1) 
    AND (OrderRel.Plant = 'mfgsys')
```

Trying to grab the first unique record from orderhead.

Comment: provide sample data and output

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions.  You can do this entirely in the `FROM` clause:

```
FROM Customer c INNER JOIN
     (SELECT oh.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company, BTCustNum ORDER BY OrderDate ASC) as seqnum
      FROM OrderHead oh
     ) oh
     ON c.Company = oh.Company AND
        c.CustNum = oh.BTCustNum AND
        oh.seqnum = 1 INNER JOIN
     OrderRel orr
     ON oh.OrderNum = orr.OrderNum
```

Note that I replaced the table names with simpler table aliases, which you should repeat in the rest of the query.